# Free pascal can't write to a text file

Tags: pascal, file-handling, freepascal

I'm trying to write something to a text file in free pascal, but it doesn't write anything.

Here is my code:

```
program start;

uses crt;

type txt = file of string;

var 
    h : string;
    f : txt;

begin
    assign(f,'hey.txt');
    rewrite(f);
    h := 'jmhtdjh';
    write(f,h);
    close(f);
    readkey;
end.
```

Comment: @lurker: Thanks a lot **lurker**, I fixed it but it still  dosen't work.

Comment: That's odd. I can compile your program, run it, and `hey.txt` appears in the current folder with the contents "jmhtdjh". There's no line feed at the end, so make sure you check the front of your command prompt as it will be all smooshed together.

Answer (score 4):

Before I explain about your code, please compile and run the following program:

```
program TextFileCreate;
var
  F : Text;
begin
  Assign(F, 'C:\temp\test.txt');
  Rewrite(F);
  Writeln(F, 'testing ...');
  Close(F);
  Readln;
end.
```

That compiles and runs fine on Windows 10 and you can confirm that it does
by using Notepad to open the file.  It uses the built-in `Text` file type which is specifically
for working with .Txt files

Turning to your program, at first I thought your problem was just that you weren't
specifying the path where the file should be saved, so I suggested changing your `Assign`
statement to read

```
assign(f, 'C:\Temp\Hey.Txt');
```

However, when I tried to compile your code with that change, I got the error

> FileOfString.lpr(7,26) Error: Typed files cannot contain reference-counted types.

.  The reason for the error is that with my Lazarus's
default compiler settings, strings are so-called "huge strings" which can be up to 2Gb in
length and are reference counted, as the error message suggests.  FPC supports two
types of strings, these "huge strings" and traditional Pascal "short strings", which
can be only up to 255 characters in length and are preceded by a "length byte" which
records how many bytes long the string is.  You can switch between these string types using the {$H} compiler directive.

So I changed your code as shown below:

```
program FileOfString;

uses crt;

{$H-}  //  means use short strings

type txt = file of string;

var
    h : string;
    f : txt;

begin
    assign(f,'c:\temp\hey.txt');
    rewrite(f);
    h := 'jmhtdjh';
    write(f,h);
    close(f);
    readkey;
end.
```

This **did** compile and wrote the file hey.txt to the c:\temp folder and I could open it
with Notepad.  However, the contents were probably not what you were expecting because
`jmhtdjh` was preceded by the length-byte I mentioned, which is Chr(7), so in
Notepad the string starts with looks something like a hollow rectangle.

Frankly, it's not worth spending any time trying to "fix" this, just use the
supplied `text` file type instead.

Comment: In a console app sometimes you really don't want to specify the full path

Comment: @DavidHeffernan:  Thanks.  I don't personally recollect ever having a reason not to but I'm sure you're right so I've changed it a bit.

Comment: There are huge numbers of examples. Pretty much any console app that accepts filenames as arguments. If you've ever used such a tool, and I am sure you have, then you will have just typed in the filename without the path.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Oh, ok, I get what you mean now.

Comment: I would say that you never rely of current directory in a GUI app because it is seldom well defined. However, in a console app the current directory is invariably well defined and I'd consider it to be an input to the program. That's how I think of it.

Comment: I tried to enter the path but it still dosen't work.

Comment: See rewritten answer.

Comment: @huckdupr "Doesn't work" is a poor description of a problem. Is the file created? What size (in bytes) is the file? If file size > 0 what does it contain when you look at it in a hex editor? Did you get any error messages? As you see, there are plenty of details that may shed some more light on the actual problem, instead of a dull "doesn't work"

Comment: Thanks @TomBrunberg.  I confess I'm slightly losing interest in trying to help if the OP won't even describe the symptoms.

Comment: Yeah @MartynA I know the feeling.

Comment: So, do you need any more help with this or not?

Comment: @tombrunberg ,I know it's a poor description but there is no error, and the file already exists, but it doesn't change.

Comment: @huckdupr How do you know it doesn't change? I already asked you to tell us the content of the file, so what is it before and after you run your program? Does the time stamp of the file change? If you don't answer all requests for additional information about your problem, the interest to help you is soon evaporating in thin air.

Comment: it is advisable to use text as file type instead of file of string when you are writing to plain text files  ... so: var f : text